# Selecting printer and settings margins of page with printform component

Tags: vb.net, printform

How can I add printer selection dialog, and how can I control margins of a page?
I tried so many things in code (printdocument codes works but they don't show my form) but they did not work. I'm using this code to print form:

```
With Me.PrintForm1
    .PrintAction = Printing.PrintAction.PrintToPreview
    .Print(Me, PowerPacks.Printing.PrintForm.PrintOption.ClientAreaOnly)
End With

Me.Close()
```

It's working but, it does not asks for printer selection and I can't control margins.

Thanks

Comment: `PrintForm1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = ...`

Comment: Thank you so much. I have found this code: "Dim MyMargins As New Margins

            With MyMargins
                .Left = 40
                .Right = 40
                .Top = 40
                .Bottom = 40
            End With

            .PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = MyMargins".It's working too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution finally, here it is:

```
PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings = PrintForm1.PrinterSettings
    PrintDialog1.AllowSomePages = True
    If PrintDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        PrintForm1.PrinterSettings = PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings

        With Me.PrintForm1
            .PrintAction = Printing.PrintAction.PrintToPreview



            Dim MyMargins As New Margins

            With MyMargins
                .Left = 40
                .Right = 40
                .Top = 40
                .Bottom = 40
            End With

            .PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = MyMargins

            PrintForm1.DocumentName = notasyon_lbl.Text
            .Print(Me, PowerPacks.Printing.PrintForm.PrintOption.CompatibleModeClientAreaOnly)

        End With

    End If
```

Thanks anyway.

Comment: this also works:

    `PrintForm1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = New System.DrawingPrinting.Margins(5, 5, 5, 5)`